# Hiding certain sections from "quick-view" of wordpress with woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide a section from either PHP template or CSS override from a website I am working on. The snippet of concern is as follows:

```
div class="widget widget_socialsharing_widget">
```

I am trying to delete this div all together. I have tried finding the widget from PHP theme files with no luck.

I have added custom CSS display: hidden property with both Customize screen and third party custom snippet plugins with no luck as well.

The widget is built in the theme I am using, I had successfully removed that from "Single Product Page" via theme PHP file modification but cannot find "Quick View" template anywhere.

Understandably the theme does not provide me with anything within documentation. And since I have obtained the theme from envato elements, the support is not there.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: It's `display:none;` OR `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: @Amir wow, such mistake, much appreciate, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `display:hidden` it should be `display: none`, but sometimes, even with `display:none` it might not work, because of the higher precedence, on that case you might have to add important.

```
.widget.widget_socialsharing_widget{
  display:none !important;
}
```

But, sometimes there might be already `!important` added, on that case you might have to increase its precedence by adding parent classes as well. Something like:

```
#parent_id.parent_class .widget.widget_socialsharing_widget{
  display:none !important;
}
```